# How to obtain hydrodynamics from many-body quantum mechanics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, condensed-matter, navier-stokes

**Background:** It is well known that the Schrodinger equation is equivalent to the Euler equation (with a "quantum potential" term) plus the [probability conservation equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_current) (which is formally identical to the mass conservation equation of the usual hydrodynamic theories). Establishing this mapping is quite simple and it's based on the so-called [Madelung transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Madelung_equations), i.e. on writing the wave function as
$$
\psi(\mathbf{x},t) = \sqrt{n(\mathbf{x},t)} e^{\phi(\mathbf{x},t)}.
$$
This polar representation of the wavefunction must be inserted into the Shroedinger equation to map it into the system given by *continuity+Euler* equations for an *irrotational* fluid (see also [this](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.60.356) seminal Landau's work).

Now, this works for a *single-particle* system. Not only: for a Bose condensate, we can interpret $\psi(\mathbf{x},t)$ as the "collective wave function" (in the Hartree–Fock approximation, the total wave-function of the system of $N$ bosons is taken as a product of $N$ identical single-particle functions $\psi(\mathbf{x},t)$). Hence, the same "single-particle" case applies also to the many-particle condensate and we end up with the known hydrodynamic theory of a condensate.

**Question:** All this is extremely cool and kind of textbook physics... but how to derive the hydrodynamic equations for a system that is comprised of many particles and it's **not** a condensate?

What concerns me: where does the temperature or the entropy (that are typically important quantities in hydrodynamics) come from? To have a hydro formulation, we have to assume local thermodynamic equilibrium, so the fundamental object should be the [density matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_matrix), I guess.

Comment: I may be oversimplifying some details that interest you, but to hydrodynamicists (/plasma physicists) one typically observes that the individual wavepacket of each particle is roughly measured by the de Broglie wavelength $\lambda \ll 1$. As such, there is little/no overlap between wavepackets, and hence they evolve, via the Schrödinger equation, purely classically. From here one is basically spending their time discussing collision theory and statistical mechanics, not many-body quantum mechanics. If you're interested in these details I can point you to a good reference.

Comment: Hi, I completely agree with you. My question is probably not clear enough: I am wondering if there is some "known trick/approach" to derive the hydro in a similar fashion to the "bose consensate" one. In particular, what happens if we have to deal with a "dense fluid" (in the sense that the wave packets overlap) but there is no proper condensation? Thank you for your comment, it really helps to clarify the question.

Comment: There is a "known trick" in that for a standard liquid the argument is essentially the same in the classical and quantum case.  It is kinetic theory and statistical physics. (This is where the temperture and entropy come in.) There will be regime for dense liquids where quantum effects may need to be taken into account quantitatively, but to a first approximation the physics will be more or less the same as in the classical case